# Suggested reading order of "The Expanse: Origins" graphic novels

Tags: suggested-order, the-expanse-novels

I've just discovered about the existence of four graphic novels set in the Expanse universe that tell the story of the four main characters, named [Origins](http://expanse.wikia.com/wiki/The_Expanse_Origins).

Is there a suggested reading order for these, if compared to the main book series? Do they spoiler anything, or are best read after a certain book to fully enjoy them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the novels there is some mystery around the characters' origins and background.
Just like the crew of the Canterbury didn't know what their crewmates history was (and didn't care), the reader is also introduced to the characters without learning about their background.

If James Corey wanted the reader to know, he would have told us.
So read the first novel at least, before reading the graphic novels.

But there aren't really any big spoilers in the graphic novels if you can't wait.

Comment: Thank you, I'm currently reading the fourth book, so the characters are old acquaintances by now, according to what you say I suppose that I can read the GN safely.

Comment: Yes indeed. Enjoy, it's quite nice to have the backstory filled in.  Be sure to read The Churn, a short story about Amos' youth.